# What is the minimum number of chemical elements required for life on earth? Does it vary between kingdoms?

Tags: biochemistry, organic-chemistry, bioinorganic-chemistry

As a non-biologist, I assume that there are certain elements that occur in all life forms as we know them. Examples might be carbon, hydrogen, oxygen and so forth. There are also elements that are rarely, if  ever, required for life on earth. My question is not about what elements might be required for life (although such information might be interesting for me and other readers). Rather it is about what the minimum possible number of elements that any life form on earth has, if we know the answer to that question. Also, if it is known, (how) does this differ between the plant, animal and other kingdoms?

---

<sup>You are far more likely than me to know what tags might be appropriate here. Please feel free to edit.</sup>

Comment: What are you defining as life? Viruses? Prions? bacteria and above certainly, but where's your cut-off?

Comment: @bob1 Whichever entities/notional kingdoms that an answerer might consider to be forms of life are fine, so long as it is explained in the answer. (Although, I wasn't thinking of prions and barely know what they are).

Comment: Prions are self-replicating proteins that can turn other proteins into more prions, they cause diseases like Creutzfeldt-Jakob disease (vCJD is also known as "mad-cow disease"), they replicate, evolve etc... don't worry, they aren't really alive, but then neither are viruses technically, which can't replicate themselves independently of another organism and always need some part of that organisms replication machinery to function. However, if you accepted prions as life, the minimum would be C, H, O, N, S I think.

Comment: I think I would add P to the list provided by @bob1 (ATP/NAD)

Comment: Hmmm. Four downvotes, but no constructive comments to explain how to ask a better question. Sigh ...

Comment: @user338907 Is that an answer perhaps?

Comment: @Araucaria - The reason for the down-votes is likely that it is impossible to define because there is such a variety of life that there will be no 1 magic number of elements. The most we can do is list a minimum of elements that are found in all life-forms, which would presumably make life possible, but that is specifically not what you asked for.

Comment: @bob1 +1 But presumably if there are elements that are found in all life forms, there are life forms that don't need any or many more than those elements. The vastness of different life forms that exist doesn't really have too much effect on this. For example, if we know of a life form that only needs those elements that are necessary for all life forms plus two others, then every other life form requiring more than that is out of consideration. No?

Comment: minimum to have any life or life as earth currently has?

Comment: @John I suppose that it's probably best to restrict it to life as earth currently has.

Comment: then you will need basically every element aside from the very unstable ones and the noble gasses, very few are not used in some life somewhere. even fluorine occurs in some life. it would be easier to list the elements NOT used in life.

Comment: @John I meant the minimum for **a** life form that currently exists on earth! (Narrow scope meaning of (*any*). I misunderstood the 'any' in your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we change the question to "what is the minimum number of elements common to *every* form of life?", my lists would be as follows. (I am not considering either viruses or prions to be 'alive').

The following elements are surely common to all forms of life (List 1):

> H (1), C (6), N (7), 0 (8), Mg (12), P (15), S (16) [#7].

In addition, the following elements are *very likely* to be common to all forms of life (List 2):

> Na (11), Cl (17), K (19), Ca (20), Fe (26), Cu (29), Zn (30) [#7].

If we broaden things to include elements occurring in *any* form of life I would add (List 3):

> B (5), F (9), Si (14) [!Seemingly], V (23), Cr (24), Mn (25), Co (27), Ni (28), Se (34), Mo (42), Cd (48), Sn (50) [!Maybe], I (53) , W  (74) [#14].

- No element in either list has an atomic number greater than 74 (Tungsten). (In the list given by [Frieden](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5044408/) (1972), the highest is I (53)).
- For List One (and as pointed out by @bob1), H (1), C (6), N (7), 0 (8), S (16) are all present in proteins. P (15) is present in ATP and NAD. We must surely also include Mg (12), as the true substrate of almost all ATP-requiring enzymes is a [complex](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11772/) of Mg<sup>++</sup> and ATP. I can't see that any element can be removed from this list, but it could be argued that we need to add some from List 2.
- For List 2, Fe (26) is present as haem in haemoglobin and the cytochromes, and (not necessarily complexed to heme) in other components of the electron transport chain. It *might* be possible that anaerobic life is possible without iron, in which case Fe (26) needs to be demoted to List 3 (but I doubt it). Zn (30) occurs in many enzymes (including yeast and liver alcohol dehydrogenase). It might be possible for a life form to exist without requiring Zn, but I don't know of any examples.
- If we restrict consideration to plants, then Mn (25) needs to be promoted to List 1 (Mn is an essential component of Photosystem II, the enzymic system responsible for the 'splitting' of water in photosynthesis). As life as we know it would be impossible without PS, Mn (25) should possibly be in List 1 without qualification.

List 3 will probably always be contentious, but here are my thoughts:

- B (5) is present in [boromycin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boromycin) the only naturally-occurring compound containing Boron (as far as I am aware). It has long been considered essential for some plants, but this is contentious. See [The importance of boron in biological systems](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29173473/) and [Boron: the essential element for vascular plants that never was](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30289999/)
- **Edit** B (5). @john has pointed out that B is required by some cyanobacteria, and has provided the following reference: [Boron Requirement in Cyanobacteria. Its Possible Role in the Early Evolution of Photosynthetic Organisms](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/plantphysiol/94/4/1554.full.pdf).
  The authors (Bonilla et al.) point out that B is a trace element that "although required in higher plants, has no role in animals or fungi". They suggest that B (possibly as boric acid?) can stabilize membranes by forming *cis*-diols with glycolipid -OH groups, a role previously suggested to account for B requirement in plants. (References to the original plant research may be found in [Bonilla et al.](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/plantphysiol/94/4/1554.full.pdf)).

This, I think, justifies B being included in List 3: required for some forms of life (but not a minimum requirement for life).

- F (9) occurs in [fluroacetate](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/fluoroacetate) (See also [The natural production of chlorinated compounds](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/es00056a001) by G W Gribble)
- Si (14). A [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5086395/) in *Science* in 1972 suggests that Silicon is an essential element for the chick (news to me!). [Frieden](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5044408/) (quoted below) has this to say: "Possible structural unit of diatoms; recently shown to be essential in chicks. "
- V (23). Occurs in haloperoxidases (See [Coordination environment changes of the vanadium in vanadium-dependent haloperoxidase enzymes](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29990751/).  The vanadate ion is very similar to phosphate. See [The role of vanadium in biology](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25608665/))
- Cr (24) Whether Chromium is an essential trace element is controversial. It *may* play a role in insulin action (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium)) but this is not universally accepted (the Wikipedia article gives a good summary of the current position). Some bacterial can [reduce chromium](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479714003545?casa_token=Klb7T5Su2AAAAAAA:1ZRFzZVqiNCQ4girMerBM9EY-VN5_D-3IldEphZMXYGHAv5wQDfGuPAdOlDyoRDAHCNVL_qrqSQ) but this seems to be a detoxification mechanism (See also [Chromium: is it essential, pharmacologically relevant, or toxic?](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24470092/)). [Frieden](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5044408/) states "Essential in higher animals; related to action of insulin." but this, it appears, is still controversial. Possibly Cr (24) needs to be deleted from List 3.
- Co (27) is a component of [Vitamin B<sub>12</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_B12)
- Nickel (28). Urease, the first enzyme crystallized (by Sumner in 1926), an accomplishment that played an essential role in establishing that enzymes are proteins, was shown in 1984 to contain Nickel (see [Urease (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urease))
- Se (34) Selenium (as [selenocysteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenocysteine)) is directly incorporated on the ribosome into some enzymes (SelenoCys is considered "the twenty-first amino acid")
- Mo (42) is a component of quite a number of enzymes, including [xanthine oxidase](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/13081133/) and is often associated with a pteridine cofactor.  See [Molybdenum and Molybdenum-Containing Enzymes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780080243986/molybdenum-and-molybdenum-containing-enzymes)
- Cd (48) A carbonic anhydrase from the marine diatom *Thalassiosira weissflogii* contains cadmium. It is thought that in oceans depleted of Zn, diatoms can use Cd as a zinc substitute. (See [Biochemistry: a cadmium enzyme from a marine diatom](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15875011/) and
  [Structure and metal exchange in the cadmium carbonic anhydrase of marine diatoms](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18322527/))
- Sn (50) There have been some reports that Tin is an essential trace element for rats and humans (see [Case study: bioavailability of tin and tin compounds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0147651303000617) and [Frieden](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5044408/) (quoted below)), but the evidence appears to be very scanty. Tin probably should be deleted from List 3.
- I (53). Iodine is known to be a component of the [thyroid hormones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyroid_hormones)
- W (74) Tungsten The first enzyme to require tungsten, a NADP-linked formate dehydrogenase from *Clostridium thermoaceticum* was [purified and characterized](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6822536/) in 1983. Since then a number  of tungstoenzymes (at least ten) have been identified, including acetylene hydratase. In many cases (and in a similar fashion to molybdoenzymes), W is often bound to a pterin cofactor. (See [Tungsten in biological systems](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8672295/))

I think [The chemical elements of life](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/5044408/) by E.Frieden, published in Scientific American in 1972, is still relevant, and I have relied heavily on the table on p55 of this publication in compiling the above lists

I haven't considered Sr (38), Nb (41), Ba (56) or Ta (73) but from [Tungsten in biological systems](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8672295/)  it appears that there is a case for these elements to be included in List 3

Comment: Should I take it, then, that there may be life forms that have only around 14 elements (list 1 + list 2)?

Comment: Note boron is important in cyanobacteria. http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/plantphysiol/94/4/1554.full.pdf and there a few notable organoboron compounds. https://www2.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/OrgMet/boron.htm

Comment: I think you can safely move Fe into list 1, even if heme (or haem) had never existed, Iron-Sulfur cluster proteins are ubiquitous among all cellular life, including obligate anaerobes. I can only think of one synthetic biology experiment in which E. coli was engineered to grow (very slowly) without making new Fe-S clusters, but they didn't even attempt to show growth in iron-limiting conditions. You're also probably right about being able to move Mn and Zn up to list 1 without further qualification.

Comment: @MikeyC Thanks. I agree with all you say, especially about non-heme iron. (Will update again over the weekend)